# Synchronization between two classes

Tags: java, swing

I have created a GUI window is being called in the main method of another class. The window has a run button. The control should return to the main method only afterthe run button has been clicked. How do i get this functionality? Should i use threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is the classic behavior of a modal dialog such as a JOptionPane: program flow from the calling code pauses while the modal dialog is displayed and then returns at the calling spot when the modal dialog is no longer visible.

I suggest that you look into using a JOptionPane since this is usually the simplest way to get this behavior. Please understand that JOptionPanes can display complex GUI's since the second parameter of its `showXXX(...)` method is of Object type and can be a JPanel that is laden with other JPanels, components, and goodies.

For example, please look at the code from the answer to this question: [How can I make a JFrame modal like a JOptionPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748322/522444)

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> can i make a JOptionPane from a JFrame? i made a JFrame with three file choosers and 3 text fields and a run button.can i make a JOptionPane from this JFrame direclty?

@Alvin: now you're learning why you should not be gearing your code towards creating JFrames -- you end up painting yourself in a corner. I suggest that you re-do that little bit of code and instead create a JPanel. Then you can put it into a JOptionPane, a JDialog, or JFrame or whatever the need dictates.

Comment: can i make a JOptionPane from a JFrame? i made a JFrame with three file choosers and 3 text fields and a run button.can i make a JOptionPane from this JFrame direclty?

Comment: @Alvin: Please see edit to answer.